# Mostrar menús por el tipo de usuario

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html5

estoy tratando de un login y cuando el login inicie sesión se muestre los menús segun el rol del trabajador, si es admin, que se muestre 3 menús, y si es trababador, solo que se muestre una sola página; ya estoy obteniendo los datos en el console, la duda es, Cómo implementar y cómo sería la función para agregra los menpus segun el rol del trabajador? ya obtengo los datos del trabajador y los envío al otro html luego de iniciar sessión. El administrador, tiene que acceder a todos los menpus, miestras que el trabajador solo a marcación. Se agradece su apoyo, soy nuevo en estas tecnologías front.
Adjunto el servicio de los link.

**html login**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Marcación Asistencia - Quality Gardian</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="formulario">
        <label >Usuario</label>
        <input id="usu" type="text">
        <br>
        <label >Contraseña</label>
        <input id="pas" type="password">
        <br>
        <button id="ingresar">Ingresar</button>
        <div id="response-container"></div>
    </div>
    

    <script src="../js/scrip.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**js login**

```
$(function(){
    $('#ingresar').click(function(){

        var usu = document.getElementById("usu").value;
        var pas = document.getElementById("pas").value;

        var datos={
            usuario:usu,
            contra:pas
        };

        $.ajax({

            url:"http://localhost:61961/api/Login/login",
            data: JSON.stringify(datos),
            type:"POST",
            contentType:'application/json',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
debugger
                if(!response.value.error){

                    localStorage.setItem('usu',JSON.stringify(response.value.data));

                    mostrarRespuesta(response);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        window.location.href = "marcación.html";
                    }, 2000); 
                }else {
                    mostrarRespuesta(response)
                }

            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }

        });
    });
})

function mostrarRespuesta(responseData) {
    // Mostrar la respuesta del servidor en el contenedor
    var container = document.getElementById("response-container");
    container.innerHTML = responseData.value.message;

  }
```

**html marcación**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Marcación</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/marcacion.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div id="menu" class="menu">
            <img src="../img/QG-marca-principal.png" alt="">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="marcación.html">Asistencia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="verificacion.html">Verificacíón</a></li>
                    <li><a href="registro.html">Registro</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">salir</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div id="mar-asis">
        <label id="lbl" for="">Bienvenido:</label>
        <label id="nom-ape"></label>
        <br>
        <label for="">Marcar hora de ingreso</label>
        <button id="marcar">Marcar</button>
        <br>
        <label id="ingresoSalida"></label>
        
    </div>


    <script src="../js/marcacion.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**js marcación**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let datos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usu'));
    let nombre = datos.usu.trab_nom;
    let apellidos = datos.usu.trab_ape;
    $('#nom-ape').text(nombre + ' ' + apellidos);
    console.log(datos);
}
);
```

**html verificación**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Verificación</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/verificacion.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="menu" class="menu">
            <img src="../img/QG-marca-principal.png" alt="">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="marcación.html">Asistencia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="verificacion.html">Verificacíón</a></li>
                    <li><a href="registro.html">Registro</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">salir</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <input type="text" id="calendario">

    <div class="container">
        <table id="datatable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>NOMBRE</th>
                    <th>CORREO</th>
                    <th>FECHA</th>
                    <th>HORA</th>
                    <th>TIPO</th>
                    <th>INGRESO</th>
                    <th>OBSERVACIÓN</th>
                    <th>VERIFICACIÓN</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    

    <script src="../js/verificacion.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**js verificación**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 
  
  $('#current_date"').datepiker();

  $.ajax({
    //url: "http://localhost:61961/api/Marcacion/listaAsistencia",
    url: "http://localhost:61961/api/Marcacion/listaAsistencia?fecha=20/06/2023 0:00:00",
    type: "GET",

    success: function(response) {

        //console.log(response[0].innerText);
        // Manipula los datos de la respuesta
        console.log(response);
        
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // Maneja los errores
        console.error(error);
      }
})

}
);
```

**html registro**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Registrar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/resgistro.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="menu" class="menu">
            <img src="../img/QG-marca-principal.png" alt="">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="marcación.html">Asistencia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="verificacion.html">Verificacíón</a></li>
                    <li><a href="registro.html">Registro</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">salir</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <H1>Registrar trabajador</H1>
</body>
</html>
```

**servicio de link**

```
        public List<Opciones> linkAcceso(string rol)
        {
            var link = _marcacionContext.Opciones.Where(x => x.opc_rol.Equals(rol)).ToList();
            return link;
        }
```

**json que se obtiene**

```
[
    {
        "opc_id": 2,
        "opc_rol": "A",
        "opc_nom": "administrador",
        "opc_html": "<li><a href=\"marcación.html\">Asistencia</a></li>"
    },
    {
        "opc_id": 3,
        "opc_rol": "A",
        "opc_nom": "administrador",
        "opc_html": "<li><a href=\"verificacion.html\">Verificacíón</a></li>"
    },
    {
        "opc_id": 4,
        "opc_rol": "A",
        "opc_nom": "administrador",
        "opc_html": "<li><a href=\"registro.html\">Registro</a></li>"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la página de Login cambias a la página de Marcación, si el inicio de sesión es correcto.

```js
 window.location.href = "marcación.html";
```

Mi sugeriencia es solicitar las opciones del menú después de cargar la página. Por ejemplo, creamos un archivo **comun.js** y vinculamos este archivo con las páginas de Marcación, Registro y Verificación.

```html
<script src="../js/comun.js"></script>
```

Contenido de **comun.js**:

```js
// Cuando finaliza la carga del documento,
// solicitamos opciones del menú para el rol A 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://.........", {rol: "A"})
        .done(function(jsonArray) {
            // He puesto el nombre de jsonArray porque en este caso tu servicio
            // devuelve un JSON Array que contiene elementos de tipo JSON Object.
            // Por tanto, debes saber la estructura de tu JSON para extraer
            // la propiedad opc_html.

            var $ul = $('#menu nav ul');
            $.each(jsonArray, function(i, opcion) {
                $ul.append(opcion.opc_html);
            });
            // Añadimos el enlace de "salir"
            $ul.append('<li><a href="#">salir</a></li>');
        })
        .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
            var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
            console.log("Error al obtener opciones del menú: " + err);
        });

});
```

Nota que añadimos el botón "Salir" dinámicamente, por tanto puedes retirar ese código HTML en las 3 páginas. El código HTML del menú queda así:

```html
<div id="menu" class="menu">
  <img src="../img/QG-marca-principal.png" alt="">
  <nav>
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Esta es una posibilidad. Hay otras alternativas para este mismo código como:

- Usar $.insertBefore() para insertar nuevos enlaces justo antes del botón "Salir". Así no quitas el código HTML del botón "Salir".
- No esperar a la carga completa del documento HTML. Puedes ejecutar directamente `$.getJSON()` justo después de cargar el código HTML del menú. Esto es posible porque el API jQuery está ya cargado (se cargó durante la carga del header).

Te dejo a ti 2 asuntos:

- Pasar el valor del rol correcto (ya sea recuperándolo de otra petición, del almacenamiento local (local storage), de un parámetro de URL, etc).
- Indicar la URL correcta para la petición.

#### Ejemplo de $.each() con un JSON Array

```js
var $jsonArray = JSON.parse('[{"opc_html":"<li>Marcación</li>"}, {"opc_html":"<li>Verificación</li>"}, {"opc_html":"<li>Registro</li>"}]');
$.each($jsonArray, function(i, opcion){
  console.log(opcion.opc_html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Referencias

- [$.getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)